# Javascript element opacity situation

Tags: javascript, opacity

Let's say i have a div element which opacity is set to 0.5 .

I have a script which function is to draw a rectangle over the div based on the first time the user clicks with the left mouse button on the div element and the way he drags the mouse over the div.

I am trying to figure out how to make the rectangle the user draws to not be affected by the opacity of the div container element.

For example if you upload a photo to google+ there is an option to crop some part of the image so only your face is visible. Thay have this kind of functionality i am looking for. When you draw the part over the image you'd like to crop the image opacity is set to 0.5 for example but the region you are drawing is clearly showing the original style of the image.

Comment: You are trying...thats good, what should we do..?

Comment: :) i am looking for somebody to give me a solution:)

Answer (score 0):

the opacity of a wrapping element is inherited by all containing elements,

you could simply solve this by creating a png-image with your desired opacity with size 1x1px and make this as background-image and repeat x and y

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is called masking, it can be achieved atleast with svg. You could have one layer with specific opacity and a mask with the rectangle properties to "burn a hole" in the opacity at a desired location.

Take a look at this:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/#toc-the-mask-property